# Convert object instead of upcasting

Tags: c#, casting

Is it possible to upcast an object in an irreversible way which would cause a loss of data.

For instance I have two classes :

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

And this simple code:

```
var b = new B {Length = 10, Name = "B Object"};

var a = b as A;
```

I would like to know if there is a way that if I cast `a` back to a `B` type object, the property `Length` would not exist and be `default(int)`

Comment: Have you considered a constructor for B that takes an A as an argument?

Comment: Why do you ask, what's your real requirement?

Comment: @Daniel, I have, but it won't fit inside what I a doing. My problem is that I have a big collection of very large object. To save time I'd like to convert them instead of duplicating them, but if I have no choice I could use the constructor...

Comment: The real requirement is to save time by not copying very large objects

Comment: Can you do `A a = b`?  The length parameter would be hidden as `A` does not expose `Length`.

Comment: Provide a method `Copy` which copies `B` with `A.Name` but without the expensive `B.Length`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot lose information this way. The object referenced by both 'b' and 'a' is the same object. The type-cast simply affects member access from the code's point of view.

Answer (score 3):

When you cast, you don't change the object itself. It's only the type of the reference to the object that is changed.

So, even when the type of the reference is `A`, the actual type of the object is still `B`. If you cast the reference back to `B` the object is still intact, because its type never changed.

It's like looking at a unicorn (B) through a cut-out of a horse (A). Even when you don't see the horn and it looks like just a horse, the horn is still there, and when you remove the cut-out, you see that it's still a unicorn. :)